# Slow vertical scrolling Listbox

Tags: xaml, uwp

Does anyone had this problem, horizontal scrollbars for a Listbox are very slow and appear not working correctly.

The code

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="4" Name="ListBox" Margin="10"
             Background="Transparent"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Files}"
             SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.File, Mode=TwoWay}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             DoubleTapped="ListBox_DoubleTapped"/>
```

Comment: Please provide detailed information about your question and a [mcve].

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the issue in a sample example.